# Kafka Consumer Thread Subscribing Indefinitely - ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactive-kafka

I am seeing issue whereby after some time, randomly, consumers stop consuming message from a topic and there's no error that was thrown. There's not many message in the topic because this is a test environment.

The consumer lag for that topic would be > 0 and would stuck at that number (like there's no consumer consuming it) indefintely. I inspected the topic using kafka tool, i can see that the partition is assigned to a consumer.

I'm running multiple threads of consumers consuming a topic, here is the code:

```
  public Runnable getRunnable() {
    return () -> {
      final ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate kafkaConsumerTemplate = 
          kafkaLib.createKafkaConsumerTemplate();
      kafkaConsumerTemplate.receive()
          .concatMap(record -> {
            // process message and commit offset

          })
          .subscribe();
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      executorService.execute(getRunnable());
    }
```

}

My question: if there're no message pushed to the topic for a period of time, would it  be possible that kafkaConsumperTemplate.receive() would stop/exit/cancel subscription on its own? 
Or maybe the thread would exit somehow after subscription ended?

Using the reactive kafka consumer, there is no more `@KafkaListener` annotation so I'm using ApplicationRunner and spawn threads of consumers. Is there another alternative correct way of starting reactive kafka consumers ?

Comment: There is nothing in Spring that would do that (`receive()` simply delegates to `KafkaReceiver.receive()`.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. what are the things that could be making a message not getting consumed in this case? These consumers are in a consumer group, consuming only 1 topic.

Comment: I don't know; sorry; I am not familiar with reactor-kafka.